# Link Youtube Channel In Wordpress Site

Tags: youtube

I am trying to develop a site where people can find and view videos of my activities from my youtube channel. I am quite new to wordpress but I decided to use it to achieve this purpose.

I have been looking for a wordpress plugin to use to display all the videos from my youtube channel but I have not found any. I used these plugins Youtube Channel Gallery and YouTube Upload Widget, but none of them work the way I want, they are only able to import one video at a time only when you input the video url. But what I want is to for my video library on my site to update as the videos in my youtube channel updates.

I would appreciate all answers thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> **Old anwser**
>
> What you are trying to is to import all your videos from your
>   **YouTube channel** to your WordPress blog.
>
> Unfortunately YouTube is not providing any public **web service** that
>   will allow external servers to get the kind of data you want to
>   import. I don’t think you will find any plugin capable to do that, at
>   least in the right way.
>
> **P.S:** The only way a plugin may do that is to analyze the **YouTube channel** source page and get all the video links in that page. This
>   would be a kind of hack and will not work permanently.
>
> What I suggest to you is to do it manually, and every time you add a
>   video on your **YouTube** channel, you also add it to your **WordPress
>   blog.**

EDIT :

Thx to [paulj](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/25139/paulj), i've just remenbered that **Youtube** is providing an **RSS** feed that you can use to fetch all the videos from your channel, here is how you access it :

If your channel is : https://www.youtube.com/user/blablabla

You can access your RSS using : https://www.youtube.com/rss/user/blablabla.rss

Comment: Doesn't Youtube provide a RSS feed of each channel? You could parse that to feed a Wordpress gallery. Or did Youtube shut that down too?

Comment: You are completely right about the RSS feed. I’m sorry about this mistake I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an iframe for your YouTube channel into a WordPress page, alternatively you can try embedding a YouTube playlist into your site and that can act as a player for you and will update when you update the playlist.

Comment: How to embed youtube playlist in my site?